# Android application with SQLite exporting

Tags: android, sqlite

Today when I export my android application, eclipse told me that "it's successfully exported" but when I check apk file, it reach only 256kb. I think it's impossible. Because my sqlite database size is around 15MB. I think SQLite database isn't attached when I exported.

Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: In what folder is your DB file located?

Comment: You have a /data/data... folder in your Eclipse project directory tree? This won't work. You need to copy the file into assets and copy that file to /data/data on the device during application start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think resources are compressed when the project is exported? Try zipping the db file and see the resultant file size. It may be that your database compresses to ~100kbs?

Comment: Nope. I've found it's because if no data are included into apk file while exporting. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just Clean the Project and then Export it. If it not solve your problem then see the code. May be the data of your databases are generated during run time so may be the size of the apk file is less. I am not sure but just check it. ok.

Comment: Nope. I've found it's because if no data are included into apk file while exporting. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you got the sollution with the Kurru answer.